Problem not loading image with Persian name in Django
Problem not loading image with Persian name in Django

Screenshot 1
Screenshot 2

I added these two to the setting file
FILE_CHARSET = 'utf-8' DEFAULT_CHARSET = 'utf-8'


Screenshot 3


Are you sure that your images uploaded successfully? may not related to django project language
